# Producer-Consumer in C++ without using pthread library

Tags: c++, multithreading, producer-consumer

I've begun learning about thread manipulation, and have begun with a simple program meant to generate random capital letters. The letters are randomly generated and added to a char array through the producer, and any added are outputted as lowercase. The consumer simply outputs the regular capital letter from the char array. So far, I have the following:

```
#include <iostream>           
#include <thread>             
#include <mutex>              
#include <condition_variable>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

mutex mtx;
condition_variable cv;

int buff_size = 0;
char* buff;

int random_int(int lower_bound) {
    random_device seed;
    mt19937 generator(seed());
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(lower_bound, nextafter(26, DBL_MAX));

    return dist(generator);
}

char random_char(int lower_bound) {
    return 'A' + (random_int(lower_bound) % 26);
}

/* Consumer

Reads characters from the buffer and prints them.

*/
void consume(int job) {
    unique_lock<mutex> lck(mtx);
    
    int count = 0;
    while (count == 0) {
        cv.wait(lck);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < buff_size; i++) {
        cout << buff[i] << endl;
    }

    count--;
}

/* Producer

Randomly generates letters at (pos > buff_size & pos <= 26),
inserts them at the next available position in the buffer,
and then prints out the lowercase form of the inputted letter.

*/
void produce(int job) {
    unique_lock<mutex> lck(mtx);
    
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < buff_size; i++) {
        buff[i] = random_char(buff_size);
        cout << static_cast<char>(tolower(buff[i])) << endl;
    }


    count++;
    cv.notify_one();
}

int main() {
    int buf_size = 0;
    cout << "The Process-Producer Problem" << endl;
    cout << "Enter the buffer size: ";
    cin >> buf_size;
 //   cout << "[p]roducer / [C]onsumer: " << buf_size << " items." << endl;

    if (buf_size > 0 && buf_size <= 26) {
        // set the buffer size
        buff_size = buf_size;
        buff = new char[buff_size];
    }
    else {
        // quit
        exit(1);
    }

    thread production[10], processed[10];

    /* Initialize the arrays */
    for (int order = 0; order < buff_size; order++) {
        production[order] = thread(produce, order);
        processed[order] = thread(consume, order);
    }

    /* Join the threads to the main threads */
    for (int order = 0; order < buff_size; order++) {
        processed[order].join();
        production[order].join();
    }

    // free the allocated memory
    delete[] buff;
    cout << "InterProcess Communication is completed. ";
}
```

Here's what it should look like:
[The correct output should output the regular capital letter from the char array, and any added are output as lowercase.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqL8g.png)

```
The Process-Producer Problem
Enter the buffer size: 3
l
s
g
L
S
G
e
s
o
E
S
O
m
n
e
M
N
E
InterProcess Communication is completed.
```

Here's what my output looks like:
[There's no output with capital letters.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZldT.png)

```
The Process-Producer Problem
Enter the buffer size: 3
d
a
p
j
t
w
n
d
h
```

What am I missing? Any ideas will be appreciated! Thanks. :)

Comment: please include actual and expected output as text in the question. Btw there is no "interprocess communication" in your code. Process != thread.

Comment: Sorry! I just updated my question

Comment: the images and the text output are swapped. Which is the correct and which is the wrong one?

Comment: There's a lot wrong with this code. Why generate random characters in this strange way? Just use `uniform_int_distribution<char> dist('A', 'A' + 26)` and `dist(generator)` will produce a random capital. Also, inside `consume()`, `count` will always be zero since it's just a local variable. Also consider using `std::vector` instead of manually allocating `buff`.

Comment: I'm still confused...what should I change?

Comment: `count` variables inside `produce` and `consume` are not linked, so consumers will never get out of their `while` loops. Perhaps you meant to share those variables somehow?

Comment: how can you share it?

Comment: @TheCoder One way would be to make it global. Another way (which would be preferred in a real app) would be to put all the global data into a `struct`, and give each thread a pointer to that `struct`, so all threads operate on the same data without making the data globally accessible.